# npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED when I do: npm install

Tags: ubuntu, npm, virtualbox

I have this error when I run `npm install`on my project:

```
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://localhost:9099/yauzl/-/yauzl-2.10.0.tgz failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9099
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/bloup/.nvm/versions/node/v16.4.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:97:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (node:events:406:35)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:193:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:158:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to http://localhost:9099/yauzl/-/yauzl-2.10.0.tgz failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9099
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/bloup/.nvm/versions/node/v16.4.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:97:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (node:events:406:35)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:193:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:158:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '127.0.0.1',
npm ERR!   port: 9099,
npm ERR!   type: 'system'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "day4-advanced-storage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "truffle-config.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "web3": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

But I'm not behind a proxy.
I'm on an Ubuntu VM on an Windows 8.1 host with the firewall desactivated.

Can someone help me please ?
Thank you in advance !

EDIT: added the package.json

Comment: Please, include in your question the packages.json.

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu I added the package.json !

Answer (score 0):

I tried change the web3 version to `"web3": "^1.5.2"` then `npm install`, it works for me (with node v15.14.0 , npm v7.7.6)